# angular how to reset div scrollTop scrollheight

Tags: angular, reset, scrolltop

In my angular app, I have a DIV to which I am setting the property [scrollTop], based on the content displayed in DIV.
I have an angular data-table inside, when there are no values, its default height is 36.
I want to reset to default height on clicking a button which resets the values to ZERO.

I get an error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '224'. Current value: '46'.

```
<div #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight"> 
  <data-table [selectColumn]="true" [items]="LST">
                                            </DATA-TABLE>
</DIV
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ChangeDetectorRef`. It is a change collection-tree which collects all views that are to be checked for changes. You need to re-render your view when it is changed. And this does the trick for you.

> mark views as dirty, meaning that they have changed and need to be
>   rerendered.

[ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Import it in your component:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, AfterContentChecked} from '@angular/core';
```

Initialize it in your constructor:

```
constructor(
  private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

And check for changes at the end of method (method bind with button):

```
this.cdref.detectChanges();
```